# Searching in MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-repositories

I'am Trying to make a function in my Repository of Spring Boot to search for the elements who's check the condition condition :

```
@Query(value = "select *from `trash_can_response` WHERE temperature=:'21' OR distance=:'24' OR humidity=:'82' ", nativeQuery = true)
    public TrashCanResponse notif();
```

this is my data example :

```
{
    "id": 42,
    "humidity": 82,
    "distance": 23,
    "temperature": 21
  },
  {
    "id": 43,
    "humidity": 82,
    "distance": 23,
    "temperature": 21
  },
  {
    "id": 44,
    "humidity": 82,
    "distance": 23,
    "temperature": 21
  },
  {
    "id": 45,
    "humidity": 82,
    "distance": 24,
    "temperature": 21
  },
  {
    "id": 46,
    "humidity": 82,
    "distance": 23,
    "temperature": 21
  },
  {
    "id": 47,
    "humidity": 82,
    "distance": 23,
    "temperature": 21
  },

  {
    "id": 50,
    "humidity": 82,
    "distance": 23,
    "temperature": 21
  },
  {
    "id": 51,
    "humidity": 82,
    "distance": 23,
    "temperature": 21
  },
 
  {
    "id": 54,
    "humidity": 82,
    "distance": 23,
    "temperature": 21
  },
```

i want to the function `notif()` to return who get `temperature=21` `OR` `humidity =21` `OR` `distance =24` ;

i know my Query code is wrong , can you correct it for me ?

---

iam using JPA :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TrashCanResponse")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "createdAt", "updatedAt" }, allowGetters = true)

@EnableJpaAuditing
public class TrashCanResponse {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private Integer humidity;
    
    @Column(unique=true)
    @NotBlank
    private Integer distance;

    @NotBlank
    private Integer temperature;

   

    @Column(updatable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    

    public TrashCanResponse() {
    }

    public Integer getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }

    public void setTemperature(Integer temperature) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    public TrashCanResponse(Integer temperature, Integer humidity, Integer distance) {
             this.setTemperature(temperature);
            this.distance=distance;
            this.humidity=humidity;
            
    }

        // Getters and Setters

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    public Integer getHumidity() {
        return humidity;
    }

    public void setHumidity(Integer humidity) {
        this.humidity = humidity;
    }

    public Integer getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(Integer distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

  

 
    
}
```

all things is good just i want to searsh for a specific rows who's check my conditions because iam bad in query ..

Comment: Are you using Spring Data JPA? Can you show the code of your `@Entity`? You are showing your data as JSON: are you storing the data as JSON in the database?

Comment: i'am alredy add more details ..
yes iam showing it as JSON with api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method should have some return type.
You can use the `@Query` as shown below without `nativeQuery`.

```
@Query(value = "select TCR from TrashCanResponse TCR WHERE TCR .temperature=21 OR TCR .distance=24 OR TCR .humidity=82 ")
public List<TrashCanResponse> TrashCanResponse notif();
```